# Error when application is lauched - EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS React native app

Tags: ios, react-native

Error statement:
com.facebook.react.JavaScript (10): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1685)

below are the list of package dependencies i have used in the code.

"@hookstate/core": "^4.0.1",
"@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
"@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.14",
"@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.6",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
"@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.2",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "17.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "17.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "17.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "17.4.1",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
"@react-native/normalize-color": "^2.1.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
"@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
"axios": "^1.3.4",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"i18next": "^22.4.15",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.41",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.18.2",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1295.0",
"react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.2.2",
"react-native-create-thumbnail": "^1.6.4",
"react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-device-country": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0",
"react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.0",
"react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
"react-native-flash-message": "0.4.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "2.4.0",
"react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
"react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.8",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
"react-native-media-controls": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-meet-hour-sdk": "^3.0.22",
"react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.5.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.6.2",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
"react-native-pie": "^1.1.2",
"react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-razorpay": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
"react-native-screens": "~3.10.2",
"react-native-share": "^8.2.2",
"react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
"react-native-simple-gradient-progressbar-view": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
"react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
"react-native-thumbnail-video": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-timezone": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
"react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
"react-native-video-player": "^0.14.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
"sp-react-native-in-app-updates": "^1.3.1"

I have tried to upgrade and downgrade the libraries used such as firebase, tried upgrading react-native but still same result

Comment: What are you trying to do, when did the code break. I recommend you go back to the last point you're code worked and try to find the change that broke your code. 
This is not really enough information to help, but here is a threat on ios forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/38920. 
also don't forget to reinstall your pods when you change packages, the problem is probably in a pod: remove pods -> (`cd ios && pod install`)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by replacing

**use_frameworks! :linkage => :static**

with

**pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true**

**pod 'FirebaseMessaging', :modular_headers => true**